# java : Is it possible to dynamically modify the code of a servlet's method (like doPost)

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, frameworks, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to write a Framework like Spring MVC.
I'm looking for a way to modify the code of the doPost/doGet method of a servlet 3.0 deployed on tomcat using javassist or reflection or whatever so the doPost can call a service method dynamically defined .

```
doPost(...){

    ServiceClassName.methodeName(); // dynamic line of code 

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using javassist. Refer [this](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html) to write your Transformer class.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never tried it before, have a look at http://www.bytebuddy.net for a bytecode creation/manipulation library.